# JQUERY nested element selector/element

Tags: jquery, path, nested

I want only author 2 in pink, how do I achieve this using .not($element)?

i.e. I want only the second top element (author2) to be pink leaving behind the first top element(author1) on the list. Here we can have multiple such list for various types. For every type I want author 2 in pink

I don't want the ROLE text colors to be changed

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("div  p").css("color", "blue");
      // I want only author 2 in pink, how do I achive this using .not($element) ?
      //$("div  p").css("color", "pink");
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    <div style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
      <p>Author1</p>
      <div style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
        <p>Role1</p>
      </div>
      <div style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
        <p>Role2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
      <p>Author2</p>
      <div style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
        <p>Role1</p>
      </div>
      <div style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
        <p>Role2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link add">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
      <span class="controls-add-text"> Add another Author</span>
    </button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is this HTML is dynamic? Why can't you use id or class for the Author2?

Comment: Its a live element (Dynamic)

Comment: Author2 is fixed text or it can be changed?

Comment: Author 2 is a placeholder ofor a real author name in its palce. Its a live element (Dynamic), I have added a button, upon clicking it more authors are added to the form.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to  that `p` element like

```
<div class="repeater-wrapper">
    <div style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
        <p class="author">Author1</p>
        <div style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
            <p>Role1</p>
        </div>
        <div style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
            <p>Role2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
        <p class="author">Author2</p>
        <div style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
            <p>Role1</p>
        </div>
        <div style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
            <p>Role2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can do

```
jQuery('.repeater-wrapper').each(function(){
        $(this).find( ".author:eq(1)" ).css("color","pink");
    });
```

Comment: But I cant, as its a live element on the form and that needs to be done using  jquery path ( counting the second element in the author list)

Comment: Sure thanks you But what if I dont have the class .author ? Its a nested template ( form ) thats used again for funders, contributors, related publications, etc ?

Comment: @nab. Check this updated answer. You can add class to main `div` which is getting repeated. Like I have added `repeater-wrapper`

Comment: var $divs = $root.find('p').not (  $root.find('p p') )  // I am trying to achieve with something like this with the concept of xpath, could you help ? $divs[2].css("color", "pink")

Comment: @nab But you can simply apply class and do thing easier, instead of making it complex

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same selector that you are using but then you can define which of the following want to treat.
For example if each author will have Role1 and Role2 this means that you will have 3

for Author.

```
$($("div p")[3]).css("color","pink")
```

Or also you can loop to the results and just change the one you want, for example:

```
$("div p").each(function(i){
    if($(this).html() == "Author2"){
        $(this).css("color","pink")
    }   
});
```

Another solution would be assigning a class to each author and take the second one. With this it doesn't matter if they have role or not.

```
<h2>What will $("div span") select?</h2>

<h4>This div element has two descendants, p and span:</h4>

<div>
    <div style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
        <p class="Author">Author1</p>
        <div style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
            <p>Role1</p>
        </div>
        <div style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
            <p>Role2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
        <p class="Author">Author2</p>
        <div style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
            <p>Role1</p>
        </div>
        <div style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
            <p>Role2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you just change the color like this:

```
$($(".Author")[1]).css("color","pink");
```

Comment: var $divs = $root.find('p').not (  $root.find('p p') )  // I am trying to achieve with something like this with the concept of xpath, could you help ? $divs[2].css("color", "pink")

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("p").parent("div").parent("div").eq(2).children("p:eq(0)").css("color", "pink")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>What will $("div span") select?</h2>

<h4>This div element has two descendants, p and span:</h4>

<div>
    <div style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
        <p>Author1</p>
        <div style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
            <p>Role1</p>
        </div>
        <div style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
            <p>Role2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
        <p>Author2</p>
        <div style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
            <p>Role1</p>
        </div>
        <div style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
            <p>Role2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: var $divs = $root.find('p').not (  $root.find('p p') )  // I am trying to achieve with something like this with the concept of xpath, could you help ? $divs[2].css("color", "pink")

Comment: `$("div:has(div>p):eq(2)").children("p:eq(0)")` it will select Author2